# Tenho um formulário de busca com 3 campos, pelo menos um dos dois primeiros devem estar preenchidos, o outro é opcional

Tags: jquery

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="input1" type="text">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2">Input 2</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="input2" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input3">Input 3</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="input3" type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

Preciso usar o jQuery Validation Plugin para ter certeza de que o usuário preencheu pelo menos o `input1` **ou o** `input2` e que mostre abaixo de cada um a mensagem "*campo 1 e campo 2 devem ser preenchidos*". Isto é possível?

Comment: Por favor, estamos no [pt.so], então traduza sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar o plugin, você precisa atribuir um `name` aos campos:

```
                                             ↓
<input class="form-control input-sm" name="input1" id="input1" type="text">
```

E deve carregar o plugin:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Em seguida aplicar o plugin ao `form`, definindo as regras para os campos (você pode definir outras regras como: mínimo de caracteres, se deve ser um e-mail etc). Abaixo eu só defini que os dois campos são necessários preenchimentos (`required`):

```
$().ready(function() {
   $("form").validate({
      rules: {
         input1: "required",
         input2: "required"
      }
   });
});
```

**[Documentação do plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)**

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
$().ready(function() {
   $("form").validate({
      rules: {
         input1: "required",
         input2: "required"
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" name="input1" id="input1" type="text">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2">Input 2</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" name="input2" id="input2" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input3">Input 3</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="input3" type="text">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```